# Remove or don't remove attribute based on window width

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, hyperlink

I'm trying to remove clickability from all phone links for desktop, etc. Basically, when the window is larger than 640px. I came up with the code below, and it worked on a particular wordpress site I did before, but this time I'm doing it on joomla (I'm not even sure if that's relevant) and it just always removes the attribute, regardless of the window width. I can't figure out whether I'm missing an `else` clause, or what that clause should even be.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery(window).ready(function() {
        if (jQuery(window).width() > 640) {
        jQuery('a[href^=tel]').removeAttr("href");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: it may be that the window is in fact larger if you are testing on a mobile device and the meta viewport tags haven't been set properly. What have you tried in terms of debugging?

Comment: I tested on both desktop and phone - it's the same across. In terms of viewport, I tried <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"> and <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> . Same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why now try something like this in your css?

```
@media only screen and (min-width:640px) {
    #path .to .div a {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

Where are you putting the JS in? If you're putting it in through the regular text editor on an article or module, it's probably being stripped out for security reasons. If you're putting it into the template's main JS file, that's more interesting.

Comment: amazing. I wasn't aware of this CSS rule.